# Sending Rainmeter "Bangs" with Autoit

Tags: autoit, rainmeter

I need some sort of clue or help while sending Rainmeter bangs through Autoit.

I have posted on the AutoIt forum for support on this issue but no one has been willing to help.
Post: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/203535-running-a-exe-with-variables-rainmeter/

I just recently posted on the Rainmeter forum as well asking for help.
Post: https://forum.rainmeter.net/viewtopic.php?f=103&t=35808&p=181229#p181229

The posts above will be able to explain a bit about what I want to do but I will summarize. So I want to send bangs that execute with a variable attached to them through ShellExecute in Autoit or by running "Run(@ComSpec & " /c " &".

```
Global $fileFolder = "Minimalist Weather Standalone\"
Global $fileINI = "Minimalist Weather.ini"
Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & '""C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe" !DeactivateConfig"' & $fileFolder & $fileINI, @SystemDir, @SW_HIDE)
```

I have not been able to be successful with this task and was wondering if anyone here would know?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Global $fileFolder = "Minimalist Weather Standalone\"
ShellExecute("C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe", '!DeactivateConfig ' & '"' & $fileFolder & '"')
```